# How to send twitter messages from array in reverse order?

Tags: php, arrays, twitter

I'm using the code below to split a long message into multiple short messages.
What is the easiest way to reverse the sending order, so the last message gets send first?

(messages should be send in this order `3>2>1` instead of the current `1>2>3`)

```
function split_to_chunks($to,$text){
    $total_length = (137 - strlen($to));
    $text_arr = explode(" ",$text);
    $i=0;
    $message[0]="";
    foreach ($text_arr as $word){
        if ( strlen($message[$i] . $word . ' ') <= $total_length ){
            if ($text_arr[count($text_arr)-1] == $word){
                $message[$i] .= $word;
            } else {
                $message[$i] .= $word . ' ';
            }
        } else {
            $i++;
            if ($text_arr[count($text_arr)-1] == $word){
                $message[$i] = $word;
            } else {
                $message[$i] = $word . ' ';
            }
        }
    }


$length = count($message);

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if($i < $length-1){
$status = new Tweet();
$status->set($message[$i]."...");
  } else {
$status = new Tweet();
$status->set($message[$i]);
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `$message[$length - $i - 1]`?

Comment: @Jay Hope that helps, your code at present is basically unmaintainable so I've refactored it to be workable and easy to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use `array_reverse` just before your `foreach` loop

The function [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) will allow you to reverse your `$message` array before doing a `for` loop (why not a `foreach`? it looks like you're going over everything anyway).

**A simple refactor of this code**

First of all, your code should be two functions because it's performing two fairly unrelated tasks. If you want to have a wrapper function to call both, by all means do so.

So, here's the function to separate input text into tweets:

```
// This function will separate an arbitrary length input text into 137 or less chatracter tweets.
function separateTextIntoTweets($input, $reversed = true) {

    // Remove line breaks from input, then allocate to an array
    $input = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $input));
    $text_arr = explode(" ", $input);

    $tweets  = array();
    $tweet = "";

    // Using a while loop, we can check the length of $text_arr on each iteration
    while(!empty($text_arr)) {
        // Take first word out of the array
        $word = array_shift($text_arr);
        if(strlen($tweet) + strlen($word) < 137) { // Fits in this tweet
            $tweet .= " $word";
        } else { // Does not fit in this tweet
            $tweets[] = trim($tweet);
            $tweet    = $word;
        }
    }

    // If there's a leftover tweet, add it to the array
    if(!empty($tweet)) $tweets[] = $tweet;

    // Return tweets in the reversed order unless $reversed is false
    return ($reversed) ? array_reverse($tweets) : $tweets;
}
```

[Live demonstration of this](https://eval.in/47046).

And this is the function to send multi-part tweets, appending '...' to all except the final tweet in the array:

```
// This function sends tweets, appending '...' to continue
function sendTweets($tweets) {
    foreach($tweets as &$tweet) {
        $status = new Tweet();
        $tweet = ($tweet == end($tweets)) ? $tweet : $tweet . "...";
        $status->set($tweet);
    }
}
```

I've designed this so you can call `sendTweets` directly on the output of `separateTextIntoTweets` to achieve the desired result.

**Some explanation of less standard features**

Explanations of the less obvious parts of my code if needed:

```
&$tweet                             
    - Passes $tweet by reference so that it can be modified to append '...'
$tweet = ($tweet == end($tweets)) ? $tweet : $tweet . "..."                      
    - Conditional ternary operator, this is shorthand for:
        if($tweet == end($message)) {
            $tweet = $tweet;
        } else {
            $tweet = $tweet . "...";
        }
end($tweets)                      
    - Refers to the last element in the $tweets array
array_shift                         
    - Removes and returns the first element from an array
strlen                              
    - Length of a string
preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $input) 
    - Replaces excess whitespace, and newlines, with a single space.
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and code! How do I send the Tweets? I tried this but nothing happens: `separateTextIntoTweets($_POST["message"]);
sendTweets();` (No error messages) Sorry, I'm new to PHP.

Comment: @Jay You're not giving `sendTweets` any parameters. Try `sendTweets(separateTextIntoTweets($_POST['message']));`

Comment: Thanks! Is this part correct? `   $tweet = ($tweet == end($tweets)) ? $tweet : $tweet . "...";` My first tweet missing the "..." and the last message got that "..." where it not should.

Comment: @Jay Sounds like the process you're using to send them is complicated. You can change `end($tweets)` for `reset($tweets)` if the order is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, you can just reverse the `$messages` array right before the last loop using [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function:

```
$messages = array_reverse($messages);
```